# How can I restore selected ASP.NET Membership users from a backup DB?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Had a recent issue with my CMS and discovered today that all of my users created in the last week were deleted.  The good news is that I have a backup of the DB, and that it uses standard ASP.NET Membership tables.

Is there a way to do a restore of this data without restoring the whole DB?  The membership tables are something of a maze... is there an existing stored proc or utility out there?  I'm not sure which tables would be required and which ones would not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any single sproc or utility to do this.

If you're using just the Membership, you'll need to copy from:

- aspnet_Membership
- aspnet_Users

If you're also using Roles you'll need to copy from:

- aspnet_UsersInRoles

If you're also using Profile you'll need to copy from:

- aspnet_Profile

So basically it's not that bad.  You just need to roll up your sleeves and write between 2 and 4 insert statements. (that's the theory at least)

Comment: Thanks Greg.  This is exactly what I just did... :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up to Greg's correct answer... here is the actual SQL script I used:

```
INSERT INTO aspnet_Users
SELECT * FROM Restored.dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT UserId FROM aspnet_Users)

INSERT INTO aspnet_Membership
SELECT * FROM Restored.dbo.aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM aspnet_Membership)

INSERT INTO aspnet_Profile
SELECT * FROM Restored.dbo.aspnet_Profile WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM aspnet_Profile)

INSERT INTO aspnet_UsersInRoles
SELECT * FROM Restored.dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles)
```